# extend jekyll / octopress with db?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jekyll, octopress

I've been looking to move my wp blog to octopress (based on jekyll). 
I'd like to have the option to add a member login/registration system to the site as well as other dynamic functionality later down the line, but I like the idea of having my content static, like octopress offers. I don't necessarily need comments on the blog. 
I've read that octopress is based on sinatra, but I'm not a ruby expert. 
Would it be possible to use sinatra to achieve what I want or do I need to use some other toolkit? 
Thanks,
B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After one day of no replies you're already disappointed in the 'ruby fanboys'... Not surprised it stays silent after such a comment.

Anyway, both Jekyll and Octopress are specifically aimed at generating static pages. You put the generated HTML files on a server and that's it. So there is no dynamic element at all. So if you want to add dynamic layers like a login system, you're looking at a totally different beast. You could create it, but you'd have to write the whole system yourself.

If you want use create CMS in Ruby, you might want to have a look at [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com)

Comment: the comment on the ruby fanboys was made because of the downvote after one day of no replies... and I see no reason for a downvote - there are probably 100s of other people who are no ruby experts and are interested in the answer.

Comment: That's why I put +1 ;-)